Extracting stitched images as a unit from pdf in C# or js
I'm trying to pull images from a pdf and allow users to select an image from a grid. Essentially I'm working on a WYSIWYG SOP editor. A user creates an SOP (Standard Operating Procedure) using some reference material and can insert images into the SOP from the source material.
I can extract the images in C# (backend) or js (front end Nuxt3) no problem; however, some pdfs have images that are essentially composite images. Let's say I have an image of a car. I extract the image and in reality it's 5 sub images stitched together. I've tried stitching the images together by detecting overlapping lines but sometimes they are broken up diagonally or in some weird shape which makes things super complicated.
I've attached my initial attempt to read images from a pdf on the front end using tato30/vue-pdf. As you can see from the sandbox below, it pulls the initial 2 images fine but then there are tons of partials that are potentially overlays? What is strange is that I also provided a url in the sandbox to a pdf of just the single page rather than the entire pdf and if you sub that into the VuePDF component, you only get two images...
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/ptmy44
EDIT
In case you can't view the code sandbox, here is the code.
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { ref } from 'vue';
  import { VuePDF, usePDF } from '@tato30/vue-pdf';
  import * as PDFJS from 'pdfjs-dist';

  const singlePagePdf = ref('https://stackoverflowrandomfile.blob.core.windows.net/randomfile/split-image-example.pdf');
  const multiPagePdf = ref('https://stackoverflowrandomfile.blob.core.windows.net/randomfile/Walmart Supply Chain Standards 2023.pdf');
  const currentPage = ref(48);
  
  let { pdf, pages } = usePDF(multiPagePdf.value);
  const loaded = ref(false);
  
  const switchPdf = () => {
    loaded.value = false;
    images.value = [];
    let returnObj;
    if (currentPage.value === 48) {
      returnObj = usePDF(singlePagePdf.value);
      currentPage.value = 1
    }
     else {
      returnObj = usePDF(multiPagePdf.value);
      currentPage.value = 48
    }
    pdf = returnObj.pdf;
  }

  const images = ref<Array<{
    url: string;
    transform: any | null; 
    page: number;
    width: number;
    height: number;
  }>>([]);
  
  const getPageImages = (page: number, documentUrl: string) => {
    loaded.value = true;
    pdf.value.promise.then(async (document: any) => { // Replace 'any' with appropriate type if available
      const pageProxy = await document.getPage(page);
      const ops = await pageProxy.getOperatorList();
      const objs: Array<{ type: string; transform: any | null; imageId: string }> = [];
      
      for (let i = 0; i < ops.fnArray.length; i++) {
        if (
          ops.fnArray[i] === PDFJS.OPS.paintImageXObject ||
          ops.fnArray[i] === PDFJS.OPS.transform
        ) {
          const argsVals = ops.argsArray[i];
          objs.push({
            type: ops.fnArray[i] === PDFJS.OPS.paintImageXObject ? 'image' : 'transform',
            transform: ops.fnArray[i] === PDFJS.OPS.transform ? argsVals : null,
            imageId: argsVals[0],
          });
        }
      }

      objs.map(async (val, i) => {
        if (val.type === 'image') {
          const imageKey = val.imageId;
          pageProxy.objs.get(imageKey, async (obj: any) => { // Replace 'any' with appropriate type if available
            const bitmap = await createImageBitmap(obj.bitmap);
            const ocanvas = new OffscreenCanvas(bitmap.width, bitmap.height);

            const ctx = ocanvas.getContext("bitmaprenderer");
            if (ctx) {
              ctx.transferFromImageBitmap(bitmap);
              const blob = await ocanvas.convertToBlob({ type: "image/png" });
              const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

              const transform = objs.length > 1 && i > 0 ? objs[i - 1] : null;
              images.value.push({
                url: blobUrl,
                transform: transform ? transform.transform : null,
                page,
                width: ocanvas.width,
                height: ocanvas.height,
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    })
  };
</script>

<template>
  <button v-if="loaded" @click="switchPdf">Switch Pdf</button>
  <VuePDF :key="currentPage" @loaded="getPageImages(currentPage)" :pdf="pdf" :page="currentPage"></VuePDF>
  <ul v-if="loaded">
    <li v-for="image in images">
        <img :src="image.url"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div v-else>Loading large pdf...</div>
 </template>

<style scoped>
.read-the-docs {
  color: #888;
}
</style>

Are there any known algorithms out there that can get join together images using shared sides?
Example PDF image from comments.

As viewed by PDF reader. For a copy of single page see https://easyupload.io/8lk59v


whats a ''SOP''

"Standard Operating Procedure" just a set of instructions to follow basically. I'll update the question

I've witnessed such PDFs. I hate them. this should not be called "stitching" because that implies the composition of overlapping photos into a cylindrical or spherical panorama. the image pieces "butt up" against each other, usually perfectly or with an intentional overlap of a pixel to correct for artefacts that inevitably happen when zooming into the document at those seams.

if I had to solve this, I'd have to find a library that gives me the bounding boxes of those pieces, then I'd analyze all pieces on one page for being adjacent (i.e. belonging to one picture). then I'd compose the pieces of each picture. sanity checks: pieces have the same resolution, pieces' pixels are on the same grid (check involving the corners of the bounding boxes) -- if you consider this comment to be a valid answer, let me know. I'd hate to leave updoots on the table

I'd appreciate it if you could provide such PDFs as example data. authentic examples please, not manually made up examples that might be different from real ones.

I've made a small repro here. Let me know if it works for you, this is the first time I use this website: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/ptmy44

Here is the link to the pdf in easy upload. Check page 48. Extracting images here yields some type of broken images that look to be overlays as you mentioned. But also, it seems to be missing some images. For example the "team lift" icon on the page doesn't get extracted. I'll update my question with the actual code I'm using
https://easyupload.io/quboav

that box with an X drawn over it is not what I expected. it's not slices of an image butting up against each other. it's just a bunch of graphics elements on top of each other. for that, all you need is to rasterize the page and take image data from that region. https://imgur.com/ec0xvX4

But how do you know which images lay on top of which? I'm assuming you use bounding box coordinates to see where the boxes lie and then create a canvas with all of them on top of each other?

overlap = intersection. analyze which graphics intersect. get an oriented bounding box or other enclosing polygon, then compare every pair for intersection.
